# Powerful GUI Calculator for Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, calculator

What is a good graphical  Calculator Application for Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What simple FLOSS software can I use to produce nice data visualization?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81865/what-simple-floss-software-can-i-use-to-produce-nice-data-visualization), also see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/399852/can-anyone-please-tell-which-is-the-best-software-in-ubuntu-to-plot-graph-agains

Comment: Looks like Geogebra is still around and may do what you want https://www.geogebra.org/ - They even have a webinterface. (I don't think this is worthy of  a full answer.)

Comment: [softwarerecs.se] is the place to ask questions like this.

Comment: @DoritoStyle Software recommendations are on-topic here. This is however a _very_ bad one that should not have amassed such a large number of upvotes but rather closed as unclear - it lacks every information necessary to answer.

Comment: On the basis of my previous comment I've flagged this for closure until OPs definition of "good" is added, otherwise it will just be a list of every calculator software. Maybe fine 10 years ago, but not these days.

Comment: @pipe My way of interpreting "good" is "useful" according to two criteria. 1. It works like a calculator works, not like an IDE. 2. It works in an intuitive way that doesn't require any knowledge of programming. That's a reasonable definition of good for a question like this, not very fuzzy in the context of a question about a graphical calculator application, and I also don't like setting impossible standards of refinement for formulating questions or else we could close almost anything.

Comment: @karel Ok, apparently those are not my criteria for "good" since I always use [wxMaxima](https://wxmaxima-developers.github.io/wxmaxima/) as my go-to calculator. I think it's up to OP to clarify, not for us to guess.

Comment: That's definitely true and that's why I commented instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Most famous ones are:

- Gnome Calculator
- galculator
- xcalc
- kcalc

They all have basic and scientific modes.

By default Ubuntu comes with "Gnome calculator" unless you are using a specific flavor of Ubuntu.

***Gnome Calculator:***

[image]

For example in "Kubuntu" you should have "kcalc".

***Kcalc:***

[image]

#### galculator

There are other options available too like "[xcalc](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Xcalc_suse.png)", I use `galculator` myself, install it using:

```
sudo apt install galculator
```

It's lightweight and really fast, doesn't have much dependencies, easy to use and has nice features.

Paper Mode:

[image]

Scientific view:

[image]

#### Extcalc

If you are looking for something with more features then I guess you are looking for "[Extcalc](http://extcalc-linux.sourceforge.net/download.html)".

[image]

Comment: I like *galculator* a lot -- it came default with 16.04 MATE, and toggles between algebraic and RPN as well as turning on-off scientific functions and some other stuff I never use.  I may have to give *extcalc* a try, too.

Comment: I like `kcalc` a lot because all I need is a simple adding machine. Now, if it only had a "tape"/history feature! The only calculators I found that have it are way too complicated for my needs.

Comment: The name galculator is not convenient for user experience because after installing it, we cannot find the app if we start typing calc (for calculator) in the apps search of the desktop environment.

Answer (score 34):

If your calculations involve units, such as with physics or electronics equations, I would recommend [Qalculate](https://qalculate.github.io/).

It supports using units in expressions, so you do not have to worry about unit conversions manually. It is also a good check for whether you have typed the correct equation (this is called [Dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis)).

[image]

Comment: I love qalculate. It works fine under Windows too.

Comment: Nice listing indeed.

Comment: Pretty cool handling of units indeed, eg 19h32min−16h45min = 2 h + 47 min

Answer (score 31):

I am personally a fan of [speedcrunch](http://speedcrunch.org/), because it has a decent list of common physical and chemical constants and remembers your history across sessions:

[image]

As noted [in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078571/any-gui-calculator-for-linux/1078608#comment1772351_1078608) by [@Michael](https://askubuntu.com/users/477928/michael):

> [It is also] easy to mix/convert hex, bin and decimal representations of numbers. With mask() and unmask() it’s also possible to reduce/extend numbers to certain bit widths.

Comment: As a digital design engineer I also love it because it’s so easy to mix/convert hex, bin and decimal representations of numbers. With mask() and unmask() it’s also possible to reduce/extend numbers to certain bit widths.

Comment: @Michael I have never used it for this, but this sounds like I might in the future, instead of doing it in Python.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can convert a result like 1333333333,33333 in scientific form quickly with Speedcrunch?

Comment: very good calc.

Comment: I am using it everyday as well, but I just saw it might be heavy. It just brought QT to my otherwise freshly reinstalled box :
libmd4c0 libpcre2-16-0 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5help5 libqt5network5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite
  libqt5svg5 libqt5widgets5 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0
  libxcb-xkb1 libxkbcommon-x11-0 qt5-gtk-platformtheme qttranslations5-l10n speedcrunch

Need to get 12.1 MB of archives / After this operation, 49.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.