# Calculators like extcalc

Tags: calculator

I was looking for a calculator for scientific use. I didn't like the default *GNOME Calculator* on Ubuntu for personal reasons.

While searching, I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078571/powerful-gui-calculator-for-linux) and learned about extcalc. It has everything I need, but the only issue is it has become obsolete. I was wondering if any other calculators with such features exist, and if they do, can you suggest them?

Comment: by the "default one" did you mean GNOME Calculator? Perhaps detail what is so wrong with it for your purposes...

Comment: @graham Yes, the GNOME calculator. The issue is that I have to clear the result every time I perform a new calculation. Maybe there might be a way to sort that out. Initially, I was looking for a standard scientific calculator, but after seeing the features of extcalc, I realized that it might help me a lot. Since I am a physics student, I need to do simple calculations, plot on the go to visualize the function, integrate and differentiate functions, and do stuff like that.

Comment: ah, ok. Do you find using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Esc useful? That's what I use to clear the calculator down or alternatively relaunch another calc over the first to get multiple instances...

Comment: @graham Ctrl+ESc cleared the history of the commands I ran in the session. But where we type new operations was still filled with the last result, so I still had to backspace the result and type the new operation. I found *wxmaxima*, which I think might work for me. It's like a Python interpreter but more straightforward to use.

Comment: @graham Shift+Esc  helped me with my issue. Anyway, I will try wxmaxima for a while and decide whether it will suit me or not.

Comment: To clear the entry window in one hit, just press the red icon with the left pointing arrow and that will clear the screen. Undo on the top bar only does one character at a time.

Answer (score 1):

One Option:

https://www.desmos.com/ has a few math tools, see if there is one (or all?) that suits your needs.